# Can't turn combobox value into a string - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, combobox, ip, resolve

I am trying to use a combobox as an input for resolving an IP address, but I have an issue. When a user selected their desired IP from the list, and click 'test', it doesn't seem to recognise the input of the combobox. If I replace the combobox with a text box, it works fine - for some reason, it won't accept the combobox input, even thought the result of both that and the textbox are *exactly* the same, they are both simple strings.

```
Dim ip As String = combobox1.Text
    _sock = New TcpClient(ip, port)
```

If I change 'combobox1.Text' to textbox1.Text, and then enter the IP manually into textbox1, it doesn't work! I also tried 'combobox1.Text.ToString', and that didn't work. This is extremely frustrating, so a quick answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedText` properties?

Comment: When using the 'selectedItem' property, it returns exactly the same thing. The 'selectedText' property simple returns:
'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Comment: Have you looked with the debugger as to the actual value, as I doubt the `SelectedText` property returns 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Comment: Well that's what it said. I am new to this, so can you tell me how to use the debugger to find the actual value please?

Comment: The normal thing to do would be to set a breakpoint, and use the watch window...

Answer (score 0):

```
'Returns the Text that has been selected:
Dim ip As String = combobox1.SelectedItem

'Returns the Index of the selected Item (ascending from 0):
Dim ip As String = combobox1.SelectedIndex
```

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: Both of those return either the Selected item's Text or Index. If you try to type something into the combobox's topline, both return "", because no Index is currently Selected, but .Text returns the Text that was typed into it.

So, the issue likely isn't what you think it is :/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out - the values in the data source for the combobox were taken from a text file, where each part of the string was taken from a different line. Therefore, instead of being 192.186.1.75 (for example), it was infact VbCrLf + 192.186.1.75, which is what caused the error. I guess my next question is, does anyone know how to stop that?

Edit - Nevermind, it's fixed now!
Thank you all for your help :)